# Пропадает интернет через некоторое время - SQUID

Tags: centos, squid, centos7

Добрый день! Тестирую прозрачный прокси на двух машинах, через некоторое время интернет пропадает...

```
######################################
# Обслуживаемые прокси-сервером сети #
######################################
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
tcp_outgoing_address 0.0.0.0 localnet
#################################################
# Правила какие порты разрешены прокси-сервером #
#################################################
# Порт SSL для подключений по HTTPS-протоколу
acl SSL_ports port 443
# Список портов, к которым разрешен доступ через прокси-сервер по протоколу HTTP
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
################################################################
# Пути к файлам запрещающих, разрешающих определенные действия #
################################################################
# Путь к списку IP-адресов пользователей, без ограничения скорости
acl Users_Speed_Unlimit src "/etc/squid/lists/Users_Speed_Unlimit.txt"
# Путь к списку IP-адресов пользователей, с ограничением скорости 1Mb
acl Users_Speed_1000 src "/etc/squid/lists/Users_Speed_1000.txt"
# Путь к списку IP-адресов пользователей, с ограничением скорости 512кб/с
acl Users_Speed_512 src "/etc/squid/lists/Users_Speed_512.txt"
# Путь к списку IP-адресов пользователей, с ограничением скорости 256 кб/с
acl Users_Speed_256 src "/etc/squid/lists/Users_Speed_256.txt"
#Запрещаем интернет
acl Users_Speed_50 src "/etc/squid/lists/Users_Speed_50.txt"
# Списки запрещенных сайтов, банеров и типов файлов
acl BlackList url_regex -i "/etc/squid/acl/BlackList"
#acl BlackList dstdomain "/etc/squid/acl/BlackList"
acl banners url_regex -i "/etc/squid/acl/banners"
acl filetypes url_regex -i "/etc/squid/acl/filetypes"
# Путь к белому списку сайтов
#acl WhiteList url_regex -i "/etc/squid/acl/WhiteList"
acl WhiteList dstdomain "/etc/squid/acl/WhiteList"
#########################
# Параметры DNS записей #
#########################
# Список DNS серверов(IP адреса), которые будут использоваться вместо тех, что определены в /etc/resolv.conf файле
#dns_nameservers 127.0.0.1
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8
##################
#Определяем радио#
##################
acl media rep_mime_type -i ^audio/*
acl media rep_mime_type -i ^video/*
#################
#Блокируем радио#
#################
http_reply_access deny media
########################################
# Правила ограничений доступа клиентов #
########################################
# Запретить доступ к портам, отсутствующим в списке выше
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Запретить метод CONNECT не на SSL-порт
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
# Разрешить только локальное управление кэшем
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
# Не ограничивать локальный доступ с сервера
http_access allow localhost
# Не ограничивать доступ администраторам
#http_access allow BlackList Users_Speed_Unlimit
http_access allow Users_Speed_Unlimit
# Блокировать интернет конкретным пользователям
http_access deny Users_Speed_50 !WhiteList
# Блокировать запрещенные сайты
http_access deny BlackList
#Разрешать доступ в интернет пользователям
http_access allow Users_Speed_1000
http_access allow Users_Speed_512
http_access allow Users_Speed_256
#http_access deny Users_Speed_50
# Блокирует все, что не было разрешено выше
http_access deny all
icp_access deny all

host_verify_strict on

# Кол-во пулов
delay_pools 5
# Первый пул и его класс
delay_class 1 1
# Второй пул и его класс
delay_class 2 2
# Третий пул и его класс
delay_class 3 2
# Четвертый пул и его класс
delay_class 4 2
# Пятый пул и его класс
delay_class 5 2

# Доступ к пулу 1 пользователей из списка Users_Speed_Unlimit
delay_access 1 allow Users_Speed_Unlimit
# Остальных не пропускаем в этот пул
delay_access 1 deny all
# Доступ к пулу 2 пользователей из списка Users_Speed_1000
delay_access 2 allow Users_Speed_1000
# Остальных не пропускаем в этот пул
delay_access 2 deny all
# Доступ к пулу 3 пользователей из списка Users_Speed_512
delay_access 3 allow Users_Speed_512
# Остальных не пропускаем в этот пул
delay_access 3 deny all
# Доступ к пулу 4 пользователей из списка Users_Speed_256
delay_access 4 allow Users_Speed_256
# Остальных не пропускаем в этот пул
delay_access 4 deny all
# Доступ к пулу 5 пользователей из списка Users_Speed_50
delay_access 5 deny Users_Speed_50
# Остальных не пропускаем в этот пул
delay_access 5 deny all
# Первому пулу без ограничения размера буфера и скорости (Users_Speed_Unlimit)
delay_parameters 1 -1/-1
# Второму пулу ограничиваем размер буфера и скорость в 1000 кБ/с (Users_Speed_1000)
delay_parameters 2 -1/-1 128000/-1
# Третьему пулу ограничиваем размер буфера и скорость в 512 кБ/с (Users_Speed_512)
delay_parameters 3 -1/-1 64000/-1
# Четвертому пулу ограничиваем размер буфера и скорость в 256 кБ/с(Users_Speed_256)
delay_parameters 4 -1/-1 32000/-1
# Четвертому пулу ограничиваем размер буфера и скорость в 50 кБ/с (Users_Speed_50)
delay_parameters 5 -1/-1 6250/-1
#############################################
# Правила подключений клиентов к прокси-серверу#
#############################################
#http_port 3128 intercept options=NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2
#http_port 3130 options=NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2
# Подключения через прозрачный порт
http_port 3128 intercept options=NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2
# Подключение через указания прокси-сервера на стороне клиента
http_port 3130 options=NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2
# Подключение по HTTPS через прозрачный порт с параметрами подставки сертификата
#https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump options=ALL:NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2 connection-auth=off cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squidCA.pem
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB options=ALL:NO_SSLv3:NO_SSLv2 connection-auth=off cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squidCA.pem
# Принимаем сертификаты, даже если они не прошли проверку.
always_direct allow all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER
# Укажем список блокируемых ресурсов (в файле домены вида .domain.com) и правила блокировки их
acl blocked ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/acl/BlackList"
# Устанавливаем защищенное соединение и считываем заголовок HTTP
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
# Закрываем соединение, если клиент заходит на ресурс указанные в blocked
ssl_bump terminate blocked
ssl_bump splice all
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/spool/squid_ssldb -M 4MB
#sslcrtd_children 5
#sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1

#########################################
# Дополнительные параметры конфигурации #
#########################################
# Путь для дискового кеширования
cache_dir aufs /var/spool/squid 500 49 256
# Путь сохранения дампов аварийного завершения
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
# Время жизни объектов для протоколов FTP и GOPHER
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
# Нулевое время жизни для динамического контента
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
# Время жизни по умолчанию
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
maximum_object_size 61440 KB
minimum_object_size 3 KB
cache_swap_low 90
cache_swap_high 95
# Максимальный размер объекта, сохраняемого в оперативной памяти
maximum_object_size_in_memory 512 KB
memory_replacement_policy lru
# Количество ротаций лог-файлов (0 - отключена ротация, 15 - максимальное количество)
logfile_rotate 0
# E-mail адрес Cache менеджера, для отправки уведомлений и отображении в страницах ошибок
cache_mgr it@61baza.ru
#debug_options ALL,9
```

Comment: какие симптомы пропадания интернета? что в файле `/var/log/squid/cache.log`? интернет пропадает между браузером и прокси, или между прокси и провайдером интернета? какие еще подробности можете указать?

Comment: Сайты начинают бесконечно загружаться, и в итоге выдают ошибку"Не удаётся отобразить эту страницу"